# Use an object property as a value with a different name in GraphQl

Tags: graphql, apollo-server

Internally in my server my entities are handled using the database's native fields where possible, so the entity's type is keyed with "dgraph.type". My graphql api does not need to know that the database is dgraph, but I don't want to have to change the field name on every resolver. Is it possible to create a Scalar or some other process so that I can send

```json
{
  "dgraph.type": "User",
  uid: "0x01",
  username: "JimNaysium",
}
```

and have the client receive

```json
{
  type: "User",
  uid: "0x01",
  username: "JimNaysium",
}
```

Comment: use middleware?

Comment: Thanks. that's what I ended up doing.

Answer (score 0):

If you've found your way to this benighted question, the answer is: There is no built in way to do this. Apollo server's plugins all trigger too early or too late to help and the schema cannot rename properties. I solved this using the following code:

```js
  type KeyedList<T = any> = {[key: string]: any};

  const getConvertTypesResolver = (
    resolver: (parent: any, args: any, context: any, info: any) => Promise<any>
  ): any => {
    return async (parent: any, args: any, context: any, info: any): Promise<any> => {
      const result = await resolver(parent, args, context, info);

      // Check for serializable data now so the processor does not choke on
      // circular references later.
      try {
        JSON.stringify(result);
      } catch (e) {
        throw new Error("Resolver results must be serializable.");
      }

      const nestedKeysArrays: string[][] = [Object.keys(result)];
      const path: KeyedList[] = [result];

      // Iterate over every nested object in the result body.
      while (nestedKeysArrays.length) {
        let done = true;
        // Iterate over every key of every object.
        while (nestedKeysArrays[0].length) {
          // Progressively destroy the keys arrays to prevent rework.
          const key = nestedKeysArrays[0].shift();
          if (!key) {
            continue;
          }
          const current = path[0][key];

          // If the current key is an object add it to the beginning of the
          // lists and begin processing it now.
          if (current && typeof current === "object") {
            nestedKeysArrays.unshift(Object.keys(current));
            path.unshift(current);
            done = false;
            break;
          }

          // Change the "dgraph.type" key to "type". This is where the real
          // work is done. Everything else is just navigation.
          if (key === "dgraph.type") {
            path[0].type = path[0]["dgraph.type"];
            delete path[0]["dgraph.type"];
          }
        }

        if (done) {
          // Remove the array of keys from the list of keys to be processed.
          nestedKeysArrays.shift();

          // Return to the previous object.
          path.shift();
        }
      }

      return result;
    };
  };
```

The function middlewares a resolver. I'm calling it before constructing ApolloServer on every resolver in the project, and using it's result in lieu of the original resolver.

The issue can be more succinctly solved if you don't avoid recursion, but then you would be using recursion. Good luck in your future endeavors.

Comment: If you're an Apollo Server guru and have a better answer, add it and I'll accept.

Comment: https://github.com/prisma-labs/graphql-middleware - this kind of middleware ? before/after resolver, before parser/before response return

Comment: That's basically what I did, just without adding a dependency. I'll add that if I have to do something else.

Comment: I looked at this briefly ... no request [pre-]processing?

Comment: No need. I'm iterating over the results and replacing "dgraph.type" keys with "type". That's all I need. My system is reserving the "type" key in the schema for the dgraph.type. I thought about using a custom scalar then mapping dgraph.type values, but that's overkill at this point. If there's something else I should be doing first, I'd love to hear it.